# Siege on Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, benchmarking, load-testing, siege

I have installed Cygwin on my win7 machine.Now I am trying to install siege tool and install openssl for testing https urls.

I read https://superuser.com/questions/144990/how-to-install-siege-on-cygwin .But I not able to do this. Steps are not clear Please provide me if anyone done that before.

Comment: maybe not all the steps are unclear to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually is an easy procedure. You can try following these alternative instructions [here](http://ulaptech.blogspot.it/2011/03/install-siege-web-performance-testing.html)

Basically, you'll download the tarball with wget after having cd'd to the desired directory (e.g. /usr/local/src/), extract it, get into its directory and execute the configure command, make, and make install.

Searching "cygwin siege howto" on Google will lead you to other guides, in case you still can't understand the one I provided.

Feel free to ask if you get stuck!